# Java ArrayList Contains() method not working

Tags: java, android, sorting, wifi

I have no doubt that the contains() method is working correctly but apparently I am doing something wrong. I am working on an android app and I am detecting WiFi and listing the WiFi in a listView. I am attempting to filter out duplicate occurrences of the same Access Point so I am creating an array to keep track of duplicates. Here is my code:

```
public void getWifi(){

    ListView wifiList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<ScanResult> apList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    wifiManager.startScan();

    List<String> wifees = new ArrayList<>();

    //split info into arrays
    for(int i=0; i < apList.size(); i++){

        String[] daList = String.valueOf(apList.get(i)).split(",");

        String info = "";
        List<String> SSIDs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String listItem : daList) {
            String topic = String.valueOf(listItem.split(":")[0]);
            String val = listItem.split(":")[1];
            Log.d(TAG, topic);
            if (Objects.equals(topic, "SSID")) {
                if(SSIDs.contains(val)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "CONTAINS");
                    break;
                } else {
                    SSIDs.add(val);
                    info = val;
                }
            } else if (Objects.equals(topic, " level")){
                String strength = "";
                if (Integer.parseInt(val.substring(1)) >= -35) {
                    strength = "100%";
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(val.substring(1)) <= -35 && Integer.parseInt(val.substring(1)) >= -65) {
                    strength = "50%";
                } else {
                    strength = "1%";
                }
                info += "   " + strength;
            }
        }
        wifees.add(info);
    }

    assert wifiList != null;
    ArrayAdapter apter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifees);
    wifiList.setAdapter(apter);
}
```

This is the contents of an apList item or what I get when I call apList.get(i):

```
SSID: SCHOOL-GUEST, BSSID: 04:04:04:04:04:04, capabilities: [ESS], level: -91, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 72500687089, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), passpoint: no, ChannelBandwidth: 0, centerFreq0: 0, centerFreq1: 0, 80211mcResponder: is not supported
```

Here is the output of that code(roughly because it is on a phone and I would rather not include the AP names for security reasons):

```
SCHOOL-WIRELESS        100%
SCHOOL-SECURE        50%
SCHOOL-GUEST        50%
SCHOOL WIRELESS        1%
SCHOOL_WIRELESS        1%
SCHOOL-SECURE        1%
SCHOOL-GUEST        1%
bxz1872         50%
...
...
...
(so on and so forth)
```

If I could just get a second opinion that would be great. I feel like I am missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually use the `SSIDs` list somewhere?  If you want to filter out duplicates, you would be better off using a set rather than a list.

Comment: I do actually declare it before this method. sorry didn't include that. it also adds to the list when an access point name is new. I will edit. I will also try the set. But I still wonder why this will not work...

Comment: can you pls provide an example of what "apList" can contain? Btw. what should be the level, if you remove an existing entry? the hihest one?

Comment: I will include the ap list as well with my edit

Comment: it has been edited!

Comment: You may want to `trim()` your strings before you compare them or use `contains`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.contains` doesnt work, because you call `List<String> SSIDs = new ArrayList<>();` within `for(int i=0; i < apList.size(); i++){`. You basically create new empty List for every loop-iteration. You should call it once befor the outer for-loop:

```
List<String> SSIDs = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i < apList.size(); i++){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something obvious. That fixed the problem.